# Exclude certain file extensions in PowerShell backup script

Tags: backup, powershell

I am new to PowerShell scripting and need assistance with some code. The code has most of the parameters I am looking for in backing up user profiles, but I need to set exclusions for file extensions like .mp3 and .exe.

How can I adjust the script to do that?

```
$destination = "D:\CODs"

$folder = "Desktop",
"Downloads",
"Favorites",
"Documents",
"Music",
"Pictures",
"Videos",
"AppData\Local\Mozilla",
"AppData\Local\Google",
"AppData\Roaming\Mozilla"




###############################################################################################################

$username = gc env:username
$userprofile = gc env:userprofile
$appData = gc env:localAPPDATA


###### Restore data section ######
if ([IO.Directory]::Exists($destination + "\" + $username + "\")) 
{ 

    $caption = "Choose Action";
    $message = "A backup folder for $username already exists, would you like to restore the data to the local machine?";
    $Yes = new-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes","Yes";
    $No = new-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No","No";
    $choices = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($Yes,$No);
    $answer = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($caption,$message,$choices,0)

    if ($answer -eq 0) 
    {

        write-host -ForegroundColor green "Restoring data to local machine for $username"
        foreach ($f in $folder)
        {   
            $currentLocalFolder = $userprofile + "\" + $f
            $currentRemoteFolder = $destination + "\" + $username + "\" + $f
            write-host -ForegroundColor cyan "  $f..."
            Copy-Item -ErrorAction silentlyContinue -recurse $currentRemoteFolder $userprofile

            if ($f -eq "AppData\Local\Mozilla") { rename-item $currentLocalFolder "$currentLocalFolder.old" }
            if ($f -eq "AppData\Roaming\Mozilla") { rename-item $currentLocalFolder "$currentLocalFolder.old" }
            if ($f -eq "AppData\Local\Google") { rename-item $currentLocalFolder "$currentLocalFolder.old" }

        }
        rename-item "$destination\$username" "$destination\$username.restored"
        write-host -ForegroundColor green "Restore Complete!"
    }

    else
    {
        write-host -ForegroundColor yellow "Aborting process"
        exit
    }
}

###### Backup Data section ########
else
{

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor green "Outlook is about to close, save any unsaved emails then press any key to continue ..."

    $x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")

    Get-Process | Where { $_.Name -Eq "OUTLOOK" } | Kill

    write-host -ForegroundColor green "Backing up data from local machine for $username"


    foreach ($f in $folder)
    {   
        $currentLocalFolder = $userprofile + "\" + $f
        $currentRemoteFolder = $destination + "\" + $username + "\" + $f
        $currentFolderSize = (Get-ChildItem -ErrorAction silentlyContinue $currentLocalFolder -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object -ErrorAction silentlyContinue -Property Length -Sum ).Sum / 1MB
        $currentFolderSizeRounded = [System.Math]::Round($currentFolderSize)
        write-host -ForegroundColor cyan "  $f... ($currentFolderSizeRounded MB)"
        Copy-Item -ErrorAction silentlyContinue -recurse $currentLocalFolder $currentRemoteFolder
    }



    $oldStylePST = [IO.Directory]::GetFiles($appData + "\Microsoft\Outlook", "*.pst") 
    foreach($pst in $oldStylePST)   
    { 
        if ((test-path -path ($destination + "\" + $username + "\Documents\Outlook Files\oldstyle")) -eq 0){new-item -type directory -path ($destination + "\" + $username + "\Documents\Outlook Files\oldstyle") | out-null}
        write-host -ForegroundColor yellow "  $pst..."
        Copy-Item $pst ($destination + "\" + $username + "\Documents\Outlook Files\oldstyle")
    }    

    write-host -ForegroundColor green "Backup complete!"

}
```

Comment: Hi Ben,  i have a few requirements that i need your input on...  how  can i make the same script make increments based on the last modified date of all files between the source and destination, delete old files from the destination folder based on the date from the source after a specified period.

Thanks

Comment: That's getting a bit more complicated. You might check out the documentation for the [`Remove-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-6) and [`Rename-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-6) cmdlets. Note that you might have to use `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` and make individual copying decisions yourself if you need fine control. If you run into any trouble, I suggest posting a new question for better visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Copy-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Copy-Item?view=powershell-4.0)'s `-Exclude` parameter. It takes a collection of file names that may contain wildcards and avoids copying them. So you might change this line:

```
Copy-Item -ErrorAction silentlyContinue -recurse $currentLocalFolder $currentRemoteFolder
```

To this (note the extra parameter near the beginning):

```
Copy-Item -Exclude '*.mp3', '*.exe' -ErrorAction silentlyContinue -recurse $currentLocalFolder $currentRemoteFolder
```

You can add as many exclusions as you like.

Comment: Worked .... Much appreciated